# Induction proving method

Tags: induction

Prove by induction a result of the form "For all $n ≥ T, 2^n < n!$". Use the best possible value of T.

Can anyone show me how to solve this question? for all n ≥ T , how do I define T?

it says use the best possible value of T, can I use $1$?

Comment: You can't use $1$, as $2^1=2$ is not strictly less than $1!=1$. Try plugging in more values of $n$ to find the least number that satisfies the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

For $n <4$, it is false.

let us prove that

> $$\forall n\geq 4  \;\;\;\; n!>2^n$$

it is true for $n=4$.

let $n\geq 4$ such that $n!>2^n $.

then

$$(n+1)!=(n+1)n!>(n+1)2^n>2.2^n $$

$$\implies (n+1)!>2^{n+1} .$$

> $T=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by noticing that the smallest possible integer $n$ for which $2^n \le n!$ is $4$, so let $T=4$. Now suppose that for some $k$,
$$2^k \le k!$$
When we multiply both sides by $2$, we get
$$2^{k+1} \le 2*k!$$
However, when $k \ge 4$, 
$$2*k! \lt (k+1)!$$
so
$$2^{k+1} \le 2*k! \le (k+1)!$$
$$2^{k+1} \le (k+1)!$$
Showing that if it is true for some $n=k$, then it must be true for $n=k+1$, and since it is true for $n=4$, it is true for all positive integral $n$ greater than or equal to $4$.